# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "21:30"

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.dmc.carambola.performa, PID: 9971
              java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "21:30"
                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
                  at com.dmc.carambola.performa.Adapters.AirDetailsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AirDetailsAdapter.java:93)
                  at com.dmc.carambola.performa.Adapters.AirDetailsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AirDetailsAdapter.java:29)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:758)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
```

The rest of the log:

> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2200)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Here is the snippet of condition block:

```
            if(selectedFlight.getRoutePoints().size() > position) {
            final RoutePoint nextRoutePoint = selectedFlight.getRoutePoints().get(position);

            String departureHour = nextRoutePoint.getDepartureTime();
            String departureHourConverted = DateHelper.formatter(departureHour, "HH:mm");
            int departure = Integer.parseInt(departureHourConverted.toString()); //This is line 93

            String arrivalTimeHour = currentRoutePoint.getDestinationArrivalTime();
            String arrivalTimeHourConverted = DateHelper.formatter(arrivalTimeHour, "HH:mm");
            int arrivalTime = Integer.parseInt(arrivalTimeHourConverted.toString());

            int time = departure - arrivalTime;

            // SE nextRoutePoint.departure - current.arrivalTime <= 24h
            if (time <= 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) {
                // Exibe este valor em String.parseString("Tempo de conexão: %d", tempo)
                Integer minutes = (time % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
                Integer hours =  (time % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (1000 + 60 + 60));
                String content = String.format("Tempo de conexão: %d:%02d", hours, minutes);
                holder.time_connection.setText(content);

            }
```

I need to convert the String "HH: mm" to int

Comment: Yeah, because "21:30" isn't a number. Why are you converting from a time to a formatted time, and then attempting to convert back to a time?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please, be sure to search for similar questions already provided or provide your own research. It would be awesome if you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What did you expect `Integer.parseInt("21:30")` to return? And why did you expect that?

Comment: Alan if you need to convert this then Just replace the : with empty string and then convert it to number. You can find replace code & conversation code on stackoverflow or in google. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

It will not parse the ":" character as it is not Integer. That's why it is throwing number format exception as it is not a number